# set div full height and width in click from another div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am loading an html file into a content div based on a click from a menu bar. The HTML contains 5 tables but for some reason the div only shows the first 5 lines of the first table, then you need a scroll bar to view the rest of the tables. I want to see all the tables on a single view and only have the scroll bars if the information exceeds the screen.  Any suggestions would help.  I have tried to set the width and height to 100% on the div but that did not work. When I view the table HTML alone it looks the way I want it to.

Thanks for any and all help.

```js
function load_codes() {
  document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = '<object type="text/html" data="codes2.html" ></object>';
}

function load_mrgsql() {
  document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = '<object type="text/html" data="mergesqlcode.html" ></object>';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sidebar">
  <h2>Sidebar</h2>
  <p>Open Merge Analysis WorkBook</p>
  <p>
    <a href="#" onclick="load_mrgsql()">Open Merge Analysis SQL file</a>
  </p>
  <p>
    <a href="#" onclick="load_codes()">Common Merge Code List</a>
  </p>
  <p>Merge Analysis Statistics</p>
  <p>My Statistics</p>
</div>


<div id="content" style="height: auto; width:auto; min-height:100%; display: block; overflow: auto;">
  <h1>Merge Analysis Tracking</h1>
  <p>Welcome to the Merge Analysis Tracking Tool</p>

  <p>Look around</p>

</div>


<!-- HTML with Tables (only 2 shown) -->

<body>
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="3">Case Close Codes</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
      <td>BFU</td>
      <td>BIOLOGICAL FATHER UNKNOWN</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>DGC</td>
      <td>IV-D GOOD CAUSE</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>DNO</td>
      <td>NCP DECEASED</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ERR</td>
      <td>CASE ENTERED IN ERROR</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>FOR</td>
      <td>FOREIGN</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>INC</td>
      <td>INCARCERATED, INSTITUTIONALIZED, MEDICAL</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>JNC</td>
      <td>INITIATING JURISDICTION NON COOPERATION</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>LCO</td>
      <td>LOCATE ONLY</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>LOC</td>
      <td>LOSS OF CONTACT</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>NCA</td>
      <td>NO CURRENT ORDER/ARREARS
        <$500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>NCO</td>
      <td>NON-COOPERATION</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>P21</td>
      <td>PATERNITY 21</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>PBI</td>
      <td>PATERNITY BEST INTEREST</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>PEX</td>
      <td>PATERNITY EXCLUDED</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>QLO</td>
      <td>QUICK LOCATE ONLY</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>RSC</td>
      <td>RECIPIENT OF SERVICES REQUEST CLOSURE</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>UL1</td>
      <td>UNABLE TO LOCATE 1 YEAR</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>UL3</td>
      <td>UNABLE TO LOCATE 3 YEARS</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table class="-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="4">Relationship Codes</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
      <td>01</td>
      <td>SELF</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>02</td>
      <td>SPOUSE</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>05</td>
      <td>CHILD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>06</td>
      <td>GRANDCHILD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>07</td>
      <td>NEPHEW OR NIECE</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>08</td>
      <td>SIBLING</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>09</td>
      <td>FIRST OR SECOND COUSIN</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>OTHER RELATIVE</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>UNBORN</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>STEP CHILD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>16</td>
      <td>STEP GRANDCHILD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>17</td>
      <td>STEP NEPHEW OR NIECE</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>18</td>
      <td>STEP BROTHER OR SISTER</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>19</td>
      <td>OTHER SPECIFIED RELATIVE</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>ATTORNEY</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>OTHER</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>28</td>
      <td>FATHER</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>29</td>
      <td>ALLEGED FATHER</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>STEP FATHER</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>31</td>
      <td>GRAND FATHER</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>32</td>
      <td>MOTHER</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>33</td>
      <td>STEP MOTHER</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>34</td>
      <td>GRAND MOTHER</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>35</td>
      <td>SISTER</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>35</td>
      <td>SISTER</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>36</td>
      <td>AGENCY</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>36</td>
      <td>AGENCY</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>37</td>
      <td>AUNT</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>37</td>
      <td>AUNT</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>38</td>
      <td>UNCLE</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>38</td>
      <td>UNCLE</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>39</td>
      <td>BROTHER</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>39</td>
      <td>BROTHER</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>40</td>
      <td>ADOPTED CHILD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>40</td>
      <td>ADOPTED CHILD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>99</td>
      <td>UNKNOWN</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>99</td>
      <td>UNKNOWN</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to make the object have it's full height and not display scrollbars, instead of the other way around.

If so, you should be able to do something like this:

```
function load_codes() {
  let elem = document.getElementById("content")
  elem.innerHTML = '<object type="text/html" data="codes2.html" ></object>';
  elem.onload = function(e) {
      elem.style.height = e.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight;
  }
}
```

That should get what you need.  You may need to do additional css to remove the object's borders.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance here but this is kind of new to me. Should I be adding that to the current function or as a function on its own?

Comment: Actually, yes, do add those to the current function.

Comment: just tried adding that line before and after the existing line but neither worked (trying to figure out how to post a screenshot to show what the issue is)

Comment: I am going to edit my example to include what I think it should look like, just in case we are not quite on the same page.

Comment: Ok, just finished (and fixed a slight error on my part)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172435/discussion-between-vancowboy-and-brandon-dixon).